# How to fix ArrayIndexOutOfBounds while transposing an array with the same variable?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, transpose

The homework question is here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFNYs.jpg

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when i try to transpose the array, and the question states that only one object can be used.

`int arr`, `int n` and and `int m` are instance variables. The input for `m,n` and `arr[][]` has been taken earlier.

```
void transpose(Transarray A){
    arr=new int[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)              
         arr[j][i] = A.arr[i][j];
   }
```

Comment: Please don't link to images. In fact, don't use images at all except when your question is about graphics. Please [edit] your question, and add the problem description *in text*. Also, include the part that creates and fills the array and `n` and `m` (a [mcve]), otherwise we don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
void transpose(Transarray A){
arr=new int[n][m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)              
     arr[i][j] = A.arr[j][i];
}
```